# Creating org-tables from the results of a code block

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I am trying to create an org-table based on the content of a CSV file that uses ";" as a delimiter.

I thought it would be easy to have a source code block to "cat" the content of the file and then pass the result to a function that creates the table, but I got stuck: I can't find a way to use the "results" of the first source code block. The function I know (org-table-convert-region) expects a region to work on and I don't know how to pass the "cat"-ed text as a region.

```
#+NAME: csvraw
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results raw
  cat afile.csv
#+END_SRC
```

I'd appreciate your help to generate a code block that produces an org-table out of my csv file, which contains lines like the following:

```
ID;Region;SubRegion;Area;No
1234;Asia;India;45;2
24251;Europe;Romania;456;67
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun jea-convert-csv-to-org-table (fname)
  (interactive "fCSV to convert: ")
  (let ((result '("|-\n")))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (save-excursion (insert-file-contents-literally fname))
      (while (and (not (eobp)) (re-search-forward "^\\(.+\\)$" nil t nil))
        (push (concat "|" (replace-regexp-in-string ";" "|" (match-string 1)) "|\n")
              result))
      (push '"|-\n" result))
    (concat (seq-mapcat #'identity (reverse result)))))
```

install the elisp code in your ~/.emacs file and restart emacs.  Or, better yet, `eval` it into existence (<kbd>CTRL+x, CTRL+e</kbd> or <kbd>ALT+x eval-last-sexp</kbd>).

```
#+NAME: csvraw
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results raw
  (jea-convert-csv-to-org-table "/Users/jamesanderson/Downloads/test1.csv")
#+END_SRC
```

note the change to `elisp` from `sh` in the above.  here is a gif of it in action:
[emacs converting csv to org table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPLnA.jpg)

The code is not optimized for large files, and, to be frank, quite quickly thrown together.  But, after a tiny bit of testing, seems to work.

Comment: You could get some more efficiency by just modifying the buffer text and extracting it all at once, `(defun nvp-convert-csv-to-org-table (fname)
  (interactive (list (read-file-name "CSV to convert: ")))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (save-excursion (insert-file-contents-literally fname))
    (while (not (eobp))
      (insert "|")
      (while (search-forward ";" (line-end-position) 'move)
        (replace-match "|"))
      (insert "|")
      (forward-line))
    (buffer-string)))
`

Comment: James, thank you so much for your reply and for taking the time to address my request.I followed your instructions using the csv sample file mentioned in my question but something goes wrong: the function creates the new buffer and copies the content of the csv file there, but the hangs, forcing me to `<kbd>Ctrl-g</kbd>` multiple times to regain control of emacs.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, thanks for proposing the enhancements. I am gonna give your version a try and post here when done.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi correct: I used Edebug to figure out what's going on and, indeed, the while loop goes on forever: it keeps concatenating the `|\n` string to `result`.

Comment: James, I amended the code you proposed by adding a termination condition for the while loop. I edited your answer to reflect the change: I guess I'll have to wait for the amendment to be peer reviewed for it to be visible.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Your version works very well, thanks! I lifted the `not(eobp)` condition from your code and used it in James'.

Comment: these are great improvements.  I keep forgetting about `with-temp-buffer`. and I should have tested it with more than one simple file.  I use org-mode, but, I have never had the time to dig into its code.  I suspect there are functions in it that could do an even better job.  Still, its fun to write lisp.

Comment: Writing lisp *is* fun, but the working assumption should always be: "org mode must have something built-in to do this already" for any value of "this".  See my answer for proof in this particular instance :-)

Answer (score 7):

There is `org-table-convert-region` (bound to `C-c |`) which can do the transformation fairly simply. The only trick is to specify `;` as the separator. You can do that by invoking it with the proper prefix argument - the doc string says:

```
(org-table-convert-region BEG0 END0 &optional SEPARATOR)

Convert region to a table.

The region goes from BEG0 to END0, but these borders will be moved
slightly, to make sure a beginning of line in the first line is included.

SEPARATOR specifies the field separator in the lines.  It can have the
following values:

(4)     Use the comma as a field separator
(16)    Use a TAB as field separator
(64)    Prompt for a regular expression as field separator
integer  When a number, use that many spaces, or a TAB, as field separator
regexp   When a regular expression, use it to match the separator
nil      When nil, the command tries to be smart and figure out the
         separator in the following way:
         - when each line contains a TAB, assume TAB-separated material
         - when each line contains a comma, assume CSV material
         - else, assume one or more SPACE characters as separator.
```

The `(64)` value is just three `C-u` in a row, so the process is as follows:

- insert the CSV file with `C-x i`.
- `C-x C-x` to mark the inserted contents as the active region.
- `C-u C-u C-u C-c | ; RET`

What's even cooler, leaving an empty line in the CSV file between the first line and the rest of the lines, will make the first line a header in the table automatically.

And you can wrap it up in a code block as well:

```
#+begin_src elisp :var file="/tmp/foo.csv" :results raw
  (defun csv-to-table (file)
    (with-temp-buffer
      (erase-buffer)
      (insert-file file)
      (org-table-convert-region (point-min) (point-max) ";")
      (buffer-string)))

  (csv-to-table file)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| a | b | c |
|---+---+---|
| d | e | f |
| g | h | i |
```

Comment: Thank you so much for chiming in with your very informative reply. The solution you propose is compact and yet extremely "legible".